# Why can't I use COUNT (*) now?

Tags: php

I want to count everything in a Table to make Sites, I'm using this exact code a few times in my php file but now all the sudden is simply doesnt work anymore.. I'm driving crazy

```
$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT (*) AS Anzahl FROM '$tablename'");
$anzahl = $stmt->fetch_array();
$eintraege = $anzahl["Anzahl"];
$stmt->close();

$max_eintraege = 2;


if($eintraege <=2){
    $seiten = 1;


}else{
    $seiten = $eintraege / $max_eintraege;
    $seiten +=1;
}


$start = $_GET["site"] * $max_eintraege - $max_eintraege;
if(!isset($_GET["site"])){
    $start = 0;
}
```

All I get is:

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in /home/u144584875/public_html/index.php on line 2377

I just can't find out whats the problem, it works like 5 times in my Script but not now.
Everything is Set and right, whats the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You should add some error handling, but the problem is this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT (*) AS Anzahl FROM '$tablename'");
```

You are quoting your table name, it should be:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT (*) AS Anzahl FROM $tablename");
```

or

```
$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT (*) AS Anzahl FROM `$tablename`");
```

in case the table name is a reserved word in mysql, starts with a number, etc.

**Edit:** If you add this before you open your database connection (or anywhere above your current code...), `mysqli` will throw errors and tell you exactly what is wrong:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
// ...
$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT (*) AS Anzahl FROM `$tablename`");
// ...
```

Comment: Mysqli->errno was 0 and an error report wasn't set, also the ' ' didn't fix the problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax is wrong. Table names should not be wrapped in single-quotes (`'`). Use backticks to escape them instead.

Update your SQL query as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS Anzahl FROM `$tablename`
```

Comment: What is contained within the variable `$tablename`? Does the table exist?

Comment: Yes it does exist, $tablename is set corretly, even if I change $tablename to the exact tablename the same error occurs

Comment: What happens if you `var_dump()` `$stmt`?

Comment: If I enter it before the query this appears:

object(mysqli_stmt)#3 (9) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(2) }

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of `mysqli::query`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query) says:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object.

Obviously, you have an error, and it returns `FALSE`. Use [`mysqli::$error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to find out what it is.